# SpringObjectFactory Error in creating application in struts2.3.7

Tags: java, spring, plugins, struts2, struts

I am migrating from sruts2.1.6 to struts2.3.7. , I have added the required jar-files recommended by apache to my class-path. Please check the listed file:-

[image]

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>First_Struts2.3.7_Demo</display-name>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>Welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My struts.xml file look like below as I am have'nt added any action right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

        </package>
</struts>
```

But when I build the class-path and run this project as HelloWorld kind project on **tomcat-6 server** ,I got following error:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Class: com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory
File: SpringObjectFactory.java
Method: getClassInstance
Line: 230 - com/opensymphony/xwork2/spring/SpringObjectFactory.java:230:-1
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:483)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    :754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.getClassInstance(SpringObjectFactory.java:230)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:471)
    ... 20 more
```

I dont know why this is happening, and I am not going to combine struts with spring.
Any help would be great. Note : xwork-core-2.3.7 is causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following Jars only in the WEB-INF/lib. Remove all spring related jars if you don't have spring.

```
asm-3.3.jar
asm-commons-3.3.jar
asm-tree-3.3.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
javaassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
ognl-3.0.5.jar
struts2-core-2.3.7.jar
xwork-core-2.3.7.jar
```

if you don't have any jars listed above please download those.

Comment: Thnks dude, Its working fine now. But how to know that which jars will work great with struts2.3.7. Suppose I am going to use hibernate3.x then which version of jars should i use